# How to get the waveform with OpenSL ES?

Tags: audio, android-ndk, sampling, waveform, opensl

Or even better, how to get the size of the amplitude or the volume of the wave sound every certain time.

In fact I need the two ways, the full waveform and measure it each time. the first one for have a view of the song wave and the second one for visual effects.

this is for Android (NDK) systems.

Answer (score 1):

come on people, I don't ask for the full code answer, I just want you to tell me some advices or something that can help me. You can simply say that the question is hard or makes no sense. but say something.

Whatever, I researched a little bit and I didn't find the answer for the question, but I did find a better solution for the problem, and is a free library named **["superpowered"](http://superpowered.com/)**, simple, fast, cross-platform, and has all the functions for analize sounds.

hope this help people new to this world of sound programming